# Angular 4 view is not updating after an delayed value

Tags: angular, ionic2

i m getting some data from ionic storage and want to show in the view. The problem is that i m getting objects from storage,push it them in an array, and want to show them in view but because of 1 second delay from storage, view doesnt show the values.

Here i m getting the objects and pushing in the array :

```
this.tickets$.subscribe(tickets => {
      this.tickets = tickets.toList()
      this.tickets.forEach(ticket =>{
        let bonusStakeStr = "bonusStake-"+ticket.ticketId;
        this.storage.get(bonusStakeStr).then(response=> {
           this.ticketStakes = [];
            if (response) {
              let obj =  {};
              obj[ticket.ticketId] = response ;
              this.ticketStakes.push(obj);
            }
          }
        )

      });
```

Thats the getter for the array :

```
getTicketStakesFromStorage(){
   return this.ticketStakes;
  }
```

Here is the controller of my view, i set the array it in the constructor:

```
this.ticketStakes = this.bonusService.getTicketStakesFromStorage();
```

And getting the values of the array for view:

```
getBonusOdd(ticketId){
    if(this.ticketStakes.length<=0)console.log("array is empty")
    if(this.ticketStakes.length>0)console.log("array is not empty")
    this.ticketStakes.forEach(ticketStake => {
      if(ticketStake.hasOwnProperty(ticketId)){
        let odd =  this.myCurrency(ticketStake[ticketId]);
        console.log(odd)
        return odd;
      }
    })
  }
```

And in the view calling like that:

```
<ion-col width-50 left>{{getBonusOdd(ticket.ticketId)}}</ion-col>
```

First that part `"if(this.ticketStakes.length<=0)console.log("array is empty")"`
prints out once and then `"if(this.ticketStakes.length>0)console.log("array is not empty")"` prints out.. so there is a 1 second delay i assume but view doesnt recognize that..
Any idea will be greatly appriciated !

Comment: when are you subscribing to this.tickets$.subscribe()...?

Comment: in the constructor of the service

Comment: thats the issue, you are accessing value of tickets array before it gets the value back from the subscribe().... you can return an observable in you getter of array in service(return this.ticketStakes.asObservable()) and then can subscribe to it in your component or use async pipe

Answer (score 0):

One way to update view (there are other logical ways specific to what you implement as well) would be to use the `detectChanges()` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` class. It is imported from `@angular/core` like this,

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject that as an argument in the constructor like this,

```
constructor (private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Then inside the `getBonusOdd()` method use it like this,

```
getBonusOdd(ticketId){
 if(this.ticketStakes.length<=0)console.log("array is empty")
 if(this.ticketStakes.length>0) {
  console.log("array is not empty");
  this.ticketStakes.forEach(ticketStake => {
   if(ticketStake.hasOwnProperty(ticketId)){
     let odd =  this.myCurrency(ticketStake[ticketId]);
     console.log(odd);
     return odd;
   }
  });
  this.ref.detectChanges();
 }
}
```

Comment: getting exception of "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Okay, I think I know what is happening. The method goes on refreshing the view once the 2nd `if` statement becomes `true` (the list `length > 0`). Is your data retrieval a one time thing or does it have to happen continuously? If you know when the data is changed (or when you need to apply the view refresh), then add that condition as well as an `&&` (and) operand to the 2nd `if` statement like this: `if(this.ticketStakes.length>0 && <new-condition-for-view-needs-refreshing-or-not>) {}`.
This will block the view refreshing only if it needs one.